# surface patched in Layout

Tags: faces

suddenly the faces of the model became patched when i Layout: in the other worspaces it doesn't happen.
Does anyone know what is causing it and how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: It's best to share the blend file when you are asking this kind of questions. Are you sure there is no overlapping objects? Have you tested on other computer to be sure it's not a problem with the graphic card?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi :). This can happen when your viewport clipping range is too large. Search this site, it was covered many times before ;)